# jslint Import global variables from another file

Tags: jslint

Is there a way to use global variables declared in another js file when analyzing the file using `jslint`.

Currently I have to declare all my global variables in the header, however that's really slow and not practical.

```
/* global console, myglobalvar1, othervar... */
```

Is there a way to import the other script file like in Re-sharper?

```
/// <reference path="my.js" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSLint is probably suggesting a useful code architecture improvement for you here, actually.  Why not put all of those globals in the same namespace?

Rather than...

```
var Global1 = "spam",
    Global2 = 2;
```

... use...

```
var MyStuff = MyStuff || {};
MyStuff.Global1 = "spam";
MyStuff.Global2 = 2;
```

... or, more conventionally...

```
var MyStuff = {
    Global1: "spam",
    Global2: 2 
};
```

... and now you can simply include...

```
/*global MyStuff*/
```

... on every [other] file and profit.  If you add more items to `MyStuff` later, you're already covered.  And if you need to add something to MyStuff on the page that's treating it as a global, that's straightforward too...  `MyStuff.NewField = "new";`

That you have lots of stuff moving from one file to another already suggests they're a functional unit (or several functional units) that each file needs to know about.  JSLint is suggesting you group them as such.

Comment: valid point Ruffin, I'll reduce the number of variables per file by grouping them

Comment: Doesn't this architecture just remove JSLint's ability to detect missing globals? MyStuff.Global3 doesn't exist, but JSLint will think it's fine because it stops checking at MyStuff.

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamic language, so you really can't do any better than checking the top level of a "namespace". `Global3` could have been added in any file of your project, regardless of where `MyStuff` was defined, and JSLint only lints at *file* scope. And believe me, deliberate namespacing is a practical must-have to maintain separation of concerns once your code gets even reasonably complex, as the OP's `global` line suggests! ;^)