# Howto: reference a library in JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm using JSLint to do code review/cleanup on a massive series of scripts that interact with an external ERP system.

The problem I am having is that JSLint complains that the methods in the API are used before they are defined.

How can I reference a library within JSLint so that proper lookups are done? I have 493 functions I need to reference so `/*Global*/` is not an option.

If this is not possible, is there a better way to do this?

I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220634/jslint-import-global-variables-from-another-file) which is asking for something similar, however the answer requires a restructure of the API which is not possible for me to do.

Answer (score 0):

What's the library?  Usually, you hope a library has everything namespaced properly so it's not an issue, as in `/*global $*/` for jQuery. If the lib is internal and you can edit it, consider doing so (if you want to stick with strict JSLint compliance).

So...

```
function myFunc1(param1)    {
    return param1 + "some string1";
}


function myFunc2(param2)    {
    return param2 + "some string2";
}
```

becomes...

```
var fauxNamespace = {
    myFunc1: function (param1)    {
        return param1 + "some string1";
    },            
    myFunc2: function (param2)    {
        return param2 + "some string2";
    }
};
```

Then you can `/*global fauxNamespace*/` and profit.  I realize that's non-trivial, but it's The Right Thing to Do (c) Crockford 2008.

Otherwise you're back to the normal "Use JSHint.  It's happier because more options," or "JSLint has [very clean code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js).  You can actually hack it up yourself to ignore that error if you want," sorts of answers.

What you're looking for is currently on around [line 2459](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L2459):

```
// If the master is not in scope, then we may have an undeclared variable.
// Check the predefined list. If it was predefined, create the global
// variable.

        if (!master) {
            writeable = predefined[name];
            if (typeof writeable === 'boolean') {
                global_scope[name] = master = {
                    dead: false,
                    function: global_funct,
                    kind: 'var',
                    string: name,
                    writeable: writeable
                };

// But if the variable is not in scope, and is not predefined, and if we are not
// in the global scope, then we have an undefined variable error.

            } else {
                token.warn('used_before_a');
            }
        } else {
            this.master = master;
        }
```

Is the library public?

Comment: Oops.  You reference my earlier answer on a similar topic.  Yeah, you're stuck if you can't do the above.  JSHint may be "friendlier" or you really can edit JSLint pretty easily.

Comment: I figured as much. It's the NetSuite API so unable to edit it. I've been able to get rid of most the complaints by using Aptana Studio though, it makes it easy to ignore specific errors :-) Thanks though